# Is the initial topology pseudometrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

For $i \in I$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}$, let $(X, \rho_i)$ be $k$-bounded pseudometric spaces. Let $\rho(x,x') = \sup_{i \in I} \rho_i(x,x')$ be the supremum pseudometric over $X$.

It is true that $\tau_\rho$ is the smallest topology that contains $\bigcup_{i \in I} \tau_{\rho_i}$? (i.e., the initial w.r.t. the identity maps).

(Here, $\tau_p$ denotes the topology induced by the $p$-open balls for a pseudoemetric $p$). The inclusion from right to left is trivial. How can I prove or disprove the converse?

Comment: Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $\rho_n(x,y) = n\cdot \lvert x-y\rvert$.

Comment: Sorry, I should specify also that the pseudometrics $\rho_i$ are all bounded by some $k \in \mathbb{R}$, otherwise the supremum pseudometric is not defined.

Comment: Doesn't change anything, $\rho_n(x,y) = \frac{n\cdot \lvert x-y\rvert}{1 + n\cdot \lvert x-y\rvert}$. By the way, $\tau_\rho$ is finer than all $\tau_{\rho_i}$, so rather than the intersection, there may be hope that under some conditions $\tau_\rho$ is the least upper bound of the $\tau_{\rho_i}$, the topology with subbasis $\bigcup \tau_{\rho_i}$.

Comment: You are right! I was thinking about the smallest topology that contains all the $\tau_{\rho_i}$. I just wrote something completely stupid! Thanks for your comments. Now I'll edit the question (again).

Comment: Why did you say "under some conditions"? Are you aware about a counterexample for the general case?

Comment: I gave a counterexample (with $1$-bounded metrics in my second comment). Every $\rho_n$ induces the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and $\rho = \sup \rho_n$ is the discrete metric, so induces the discrete topology. More generally, the initial topology might not be first-countable, then it can not be induced by a single pseudo-/semi-/quasi-metric.

Comment: Thanks again! Now it's clear :)